# c# Add SQL parameter to DbParameter array if condition validates

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to add a DbParameter to a DbParameter array, based on an if condition, like  the following code:

```
    DbParameter[] prms = new DbParameter[]
    {
        CreateDbParameter("prmA", prmA),
        CreateDbParameter("prmB", prmB)
    };
    if(!validate)
    {
        // Add prmC
    }
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since arrays are not dynamic, I would not use an array for this, instead I'd use a list:

```
var prms = new List<DbParameter>
{
    CreateDbParameter("prmA", prmA),
    CreateDbParameter("prmB", prmB)
};

if(!validate)
{
    prms.Add(CreateDbParameter("prmC", prmC));
}
```

Then if you ever actually need the array:

```
var prmArray = prms.ToArray();
```

Comment: @Kevin seems like you are quite familiar with Database. Nice answer! ;) +10